# Create external .py file objectv python 3.x

Tags: python

I have this person class in person.py and I would like to create two objects from another file main.py

person.py:

```
class Person():
  

      def __init__(self, name):
          self.name = name
      def welcome(self):
          print("welcome", name)
```

class main.py:

```
  import Person as P
  def main():
     p1 = P.Person("Marshall")
     p2 = P.Person("Jhon")
     p1.welcome()
     p2.welcome()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must import the `Person` class from the `person` file (the `.py` is added automatically):

```py
from person import Person
def main():
    p1 = Person("Marshall")
    # ...
```

Or, using `import...as`:

```py
import person as P
def main():
    p1 = P.Person("Marshall")
    # ...
```